# How to vertically center a font awesome icon inside a flex div?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, font-awesome

How can I vertically center the sort up and down icons with the "Column" text?

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 8px;
  margin: 16px;
  background-color: grey;
  width: 65px;
}

.icon {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="wrapper">
  <div>Column</div>
  <div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-sort-up"></i></div>
</div>


<div class="wrapper">
  <div>Column</div>
  <div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-sort-down"></i></div>
</div>
```

You can notice the icons are not vertically aligned with the text. I've tried different approaches with no success.

Comment: the icon is centred but it's designed to have a lot of empty space. Use translate to offest it

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look :)

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 8px;
  margin: 16px;
  background-color: grey;
  width: 65px;
}

.fa-sort-down {
   height: 24px;
   margin-top: -7px;x
}

.fa-sort-up{
   margin-top: 2px
}

.icon {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 4px;
  margin-top:8px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="wrapper">
  <div>Column</div>
  <div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-sort-up"></i></div>
</div>


<div class="wrapper">
  <div>Column</div>
  <div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-sort-down"></i></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding more `padding` or `margin` for the icon:

```
.icon {

  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px 4px 4px 4px;
}
```

But if that doesn't work:

```
.icon {

    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 4px;
    margin-top: 6px;
}
```

I hope this helps...